# How to remove padding under last paragraph from NSAttributedString created from HTML using NSHTMLTextDocumentType

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

When creating an `NSAttributedString` from HTML, using `NSHTMLTextDocumentType`, I'm finding it will add an `\n` for each paragraph even after the last paragraph. This is adding undesired padding underneath the last paragraph of text that's shown in a `UILabel`. How does one remove that extra padding for the last paragraph only?

```
NSString *style = @"<style> body { font-family: Avenir; font-size: 18px; color: blue; } p:last-of-type { margin: 0; }</style>";
NSString *html = @"<p>A whole bunch of sample text goes right here.</p><p>Now here's another paragraph that unfortunately has an extra line underneath the text adding undesired padding to the label. :(</p>";
NSString *styledHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", style, html];

self.label.attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[styledHtml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I do want to preserve the margin/padding between the paragraphs though, just remove it from the last one

Comment: Try this `NSMutableAttributedString* mutableAttributedString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[styledHtml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];` then `[mutableAttributedString removeAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName range:NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttributedString.length)];` and lastly set it to label.

Comment: When I use `p{margin:0; padding:0;}` it removes the padding between the paragraphs (and \n is still there), but the padding remains unchanged on the last `<p>`, odd. Removing `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Swift 4 version:

Since you are using an NSMutableAttributedString object you can remove the newline character at the end (if it exists) like this:

```
if let lastCharacter = attrStr.string.last, lastCharacter == "\n" {
    attrStr.deleteCharacters(in: NSRange(location: attrStr.length-1, length: 1))
}
```

The reason for the extra newline character seems to originate from the way xmllib processes the html. It wraps the "tagless" string into a `<p>` tag and the tag adds a newline character by default.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if its still relevant, when I checked the NSAttributedString output in these cases, I saw that `<p>` tag adds characters after every closure with some default font settings:

```
{
NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 1 1 1 1 ";
NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7f94e932a720> font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 1.00pt";
NSKern = 0;
NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 20/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
NSStrokeColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 1 1 1 1 ";
NSStrokeWidth = 0;
```

}

So instead of using the `<p>` tag, I wrapped everything with a `<span>` tag:

```
NSString *html = @"<span style=\"[STYLE CAN BE ADDED HERE]\">A whole bunch of sample text goes right here.</span><br /><span>Now here's another paragraph that unfortunately has an extra line underneath the text adding undesired padding to the label. :(</span>";
```

Kind of a work-around but it does the trick.